# sendReminderToParticipants and Localisable.strings not working

Tags: apple-push-notifications, game-center, localizable.strings

I'm trying to make GKTurnBasedMatch's **sendReminderToParticipants** work correctly in conjunction with **Localizable.strings** so as to implement 'poke' functionality whereby you poke another player to have their turn.

1. Here is what my Localizable.strings file looks like:

"POKE" = "%@ has poked you!";

2. It's set to UTF-16 encoding as per below:

[image]

3. And here is my function call:

   ```
   let messageKey = "POKE"
   if opponent?.player?.alias != nil
   {
       match.sendReminderToParticipants([opponent!], localizableMessageKey: messageKey, arguments: [opponent!.player!.alias!]) { (error) in
           if error != nil {
               NSLog("Problem poking player: \(error!.description)")
           }
       }

       NSLog("You have poked the opponent for match \(match.matchID).  resetting poke date")
       APPDELEGATE.pokeMgr.update(match.matchID!)
   }
   ```
4. Localizable.strings is included in the "Copy Bundle Resources" of my build phases for my build target
5. I deleted the app from my device and rebuilt it cleanly.

Issue:  It doesn't work! The push notification that is received simply is the default one saying "Your Turn".  I must have missed something.  Can someone please advise if there is something else I need to have done to make this work?

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: Afraid not. I gave up in the end as I had other parts to work on.